# Aligning DIVs beside each other and Adding an Horizontal ScrollBar in HTML

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a Parent Div `chatRooms` , inside it there's many `chatRoom`'s, and the `chatRoomName` Div was made only for proper formatting.

My Intention is to make each `chatRoom` `float:left;` beside the previous `chatRoom`, then have an horizontal scroll bar in case the maximum width of all `chatRoom`'s exceeds the width of the parent div `chatRooms`, and this is actually working but the exceeding `chatRoom`'s are being placed on a second line, not beside the last `chatRoom`, I want them all to say on the same line, even if some of them can't be seen, but I will be able to see them when I scroll right.

```
<div id="chatRooms">

                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        IUL
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chatRoom">
                                        <div class="chatRoomName">
                                        CCE
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

CSS:

```
#chatRooms
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: green;
   overflow-x:scroll;

    margin-top:5px;
    height:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.chatRoom
{
    width:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;
    margin-right:1px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chatRoomName:hover
{
    color:chartreuse;
}
.chatRoomName
{
    background-color:green;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using inline block instead off floating the elements and using white-space: nowrap;

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AFGU4/

```
.chatRoom
{
    width:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;
    margin-right:1px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is needed in this case is `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`. By making your `div`s `inline-block` and adding `white-space: nowrap;` on their *parent* you'll be ensured that the `div`s will always be on a single line. Adding `overflow-x: auto;` will provide a horisontal scrolling if necessary.